# How can I achieve a Cartesian Product for all distinct entries of two fields within the provided sample data without using a Cross Join (MySQL 5.6)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's a sample data set:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `A` (
  `Product_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Material` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Type` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Product_id`,`Material`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `A` (`Product_id`, `Material`, `Type`) VALUES
  ('123', 'Mahogany', 'Chair'),
  ('123', 'Oak', 'Chair'),
  ('123', 'Birch', 'Chair'),
  ('456', 'Mahogany', 'Table'),
  ('456', 'Oak', 'Table'),
  ('789', 'Steel', 'Fridge'),
  ('789', 'Iron', 'Fridge'),
  ('111', 'Spruce', 'Chair'),
  ('111', 'Mahogany', 'Chair'),
  ('222', 'Mahogany', 'Table');
```

Specifically, I want to get the Cartesian Product of the 'Material' and 'Type' fields.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a cross join exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular `join`:

```
select *
from (select distinct material from a) m join
     (select distinct type from a) t
     on 1=1;
```

Seems like a strange request.  `cross join` is the built-in functionality for this purpose.  I should note that the `on` clause is optional in MySQL, but I strongly recommend using it with `join`.

Answer (score 0):

You can travel back in time and run a pre-ANSI join without conditions:

```
SELECT *
FROM a, a AS b;
```

It's literally the same (my server generates identical execution plans) but less readable. I don't know if it suits your needs since I don't know the reasons behind your strange requirements.